# clean up an input to numbers and decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to clean up some user input to a valid float type with only numbers and decimal points.

I found this approach

```
def to_numeric(s):
    try:
        s = str(s).strip()
        if s is None or len(s) < 1:
            return None
        else:
            s = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in '.0123456789', str(s)))
            if s is None or len(s) < 1:
                return None
            else:
                s = float(s)
                return s

    except ValueError as detail:        
        return None

    except Exception as detail:        
        return None
```

But the cast to float complains of

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'filter'

How can I get the string back from the filter?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: I updated with the answer and also added null or empty check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` returns an iterable that yields single chars for that case (it iterates over the string and yields acceptable characters). Try using `''.join` to make them come back as a string:

```
s = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in '.0123456789', str(s)))
s = float(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
s = float("".join(s))
```

instead of

```
s = float(s)
```

In Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator and float expects `str`